# Mouseleave not for child divs

Tags: jquery, html, onmouseout

This is probably very easy, but I can't figure it out for the moment being.

I have html like this:

```
<div class="current-colors">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The  `<div class="boxes">` is display as block.

Current jQuery - when user moves from the div-containter with class boxes:

```
$(".current-colors").on('mouseout', '.boxes', function(){
    $(".filter-menu .current-colors .boxes").hide();
});
```

the `<div class="boxes">` are hidden and that is correct.

But my issue is that when user moves to `<div class="item">` the `<div class="boxes">` is hidden as well. I don't want that. **I want the `<div class="boxes">` to be hidden ONLY when leaving "outside" and not leaving to any child divs.** How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/)

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

```
$(".current-colors").on('mouseleave', '.boxes', function(){
    $(this).hide();
    //$(".filter-menu .current-colors .boxes").hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fm4Fg/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn jquery not() event, look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/YXTAz/

```
$("#list li").not(".one").css("border-bottom","1px solid #000");

<ul id="list">
 <li class="one">Item A</li>
 <li class="two">Item B</li>
 <li class="three">Item C</li>
</ul>
```